# Spring Boot Web Socket RabbitMQ not available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, rabbitmq, spring-websocket

I have simple spring boot app with web socket configuration.

When i run my app with SimpleBroker(provided by spring) everything works fine, but when i want to use rabbitmq instead of SimpleBroker, i have some problems, my broker is "not available"

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
open class WebSocketConfig : ILogging by LoggingImp<WebSocketConfig>(), 
WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Autowired
private lateinit var env: Environment

override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hig").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS()
}

override fun configureMessageBroker(registry: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
    val host = env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.host")!!
    val port = env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.port")!!.toInt()
    val login = env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.username")!!
    val pass = env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.password")!!
    log.debug("webSocket=$host, $port, $login, $pass")
//        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chat")
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/chat")
            .setRelayHost(host)
            .setRelayPort(port)
            .setClientLogin(login)
            .setClientPasscode(pass)
            .setAutoStartup(true)
            .setSystemHeartbeatReceiveInterval(10000)
            .setSystemHeartbeatSendInterval(10000)
    }

}
```

response from WebSocketMessageBrokerStats:

```
{
"loggingPeriod": 1800000,
"webSocketSessionStatsInfo": "0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)",
"stompSubProtocolStatsInfo": "processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)",
"stompBrokerRelayStatsInfo": "1 sessions, localhost:5672 (not available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)",
"clientInboundExecutorStatsInfo": "pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0",
"clientOutboundExecutorStatsInfo": "pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0",
"sockJsTaskSchedulerStatsInfo": "pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 0"
}
```

Broker details:

[image: Overview]

[image: Connections]

```
2018-02-15 23:03:56.367 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/hig/websocket]
2018-02-15 23:03:56.367 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /hig/websocket
2018-02-15 23:03:56.368 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/hig/websocket]
2018-02-15 23:03:56.368 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/hig/websocket] are [/hig/**]
2018-02-15 23:03:56.368 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/hig/websocket] are {}
2018-02-15 23:03:56.368 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHandlerMapping - Mapping [/hig/websocket] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler@352c1b98] and 1 interceptor
2018-02-15 23:03:56.368 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/hig/websocket] is: -1
2018-02-15 23:03:56.369 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.t.h.DefaultSockJsService - Processing transport request: GET http://localhost:8080/hig/websocket
2018-02-15 23:03:56.370 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-02-15 23:03:56.370 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
2018-02-15 23:03:56.371 [XNIO-2 task-16] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - New StandardWebSocketSession[id=Enl3glxP29UhO95gUafWViRXrXaZn3Kv556EVxW4, uri=/hig/websocket]
2018-02-15 23:03:56.374 [clientOutboundChannel-7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.a.NativeWebSocketSession - Closing StandardWebSocketSession[id=Enl3glxP29UhO95gUafWViRXrXaZn3Kv556EVxW4, uri=/hig/websocket]
2018-02-15 23:03:56.374 [clientOutboundChannel-7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - StandardWebSocketSession[id=Enl3glxP29UhO95gUafWViRXrXaZn3Kv556EVxW4, uri=/hig/websocket] closed with CloseStatus[code=1002, reason=]
2018-02-15 23:03:56.374 [clientOutboundChannel-7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler - Clearing session Enl3glxP29UhO95gUafWViRXrXaZn3Kv556EVxW4
2018-02-15 23:03:56.375 [clientOutboundChannel-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler - No session for GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=OTHER, stompCommand=ERROR, nativeHeaders={message=[Broker not available.]}, simpSessionId=Enl3glxP29UhO95gUafWViRXrXaZn3Kv556EVxW4}]
```

For client i'm using angular 5

When i'm using `registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chat")` everything works fine

When i enable `registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/chat")...` i'm getting:

message:Broker not available.
content-length:0

pom.xml:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.ipc</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.21.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to connect using stomp protocol on a rabbitmq which doesn't run the stomp adapter.
Run:

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp`

to enable stomp.

Also, you are connecting to the port 5672 which is the amqp protocol / adapter. This is why you have this `stompCommand=ERROR, nativeHeaders={message=[Broker not available.]}`.
Once enabled, the stomp adapter will by default listen on tcp/61613.

Comment: My dockerfile shows:
run rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_web_stomp

EXPOSE 15674

is it correct?